# Как получить объект типа IGuild Discord.NET

Tags: c#, discord

Мне нужно получить объект типа `Discord.IGuild`. Интерфейс реализовывать нельзя: не знаю как.

```
public async Task Reports(string str)
{
    IGuild guild; // тут нужно получить объект типа `IGuild`
    
    var cache = new CacheMode();
        
    var guildId = guild.GetChannelAsync(716962668900122654, cache);    
}
```

Comment: что? можете показать пример того, что у вас не получается?

Comment: @timur да щас 2 минуты

Comment: @timur отредактировал вопрос

Comment: ну так тут же переменная guild не инициализирована

Comment: @timur IGuild guild = new IGuild(); вот так надо?

Comment: Интерфейс – это набор методов для обкаста: у интерфейса нет конструкторов. Попробуйте получить объект типа `IGuild` через метод или через конструктор класса, реализующего интерфейс `IGuild`

Comment: [ссылка #1](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.9.php), [ссылка #2](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/) (справка по интерфейсам .NET)

Comment: @return Вы мне скинули, интерфейсы которые наследуются, а мне нужно использовать интефейс из документации, я не могу его наследовать

Comment: Вы не можете наследовать интерфейс? Это в какой вселенной? И вообще, добавьте код в вопрос. Без него мало что понятно.

Comment: Вы можете получить объект из метода `IGuild GetGuild()` или реализовать интерфейс `public class MyGuild : IGuild`. Интерфейсы наследовать нельзя – можно только реализовать

Comment: В доке должно быть всё написано, как и где получать ваш `IGuild`

Comment: Щас у меня отлагает VS и я вам покажу почему я не могу наследовать интерфейс

Comment: Потому что вы не можете реализовать его методов из-за незнания реализации :)

Comment: @V-Mor Если, я добавлю в наследования интефейс IGuild, то  у меня студия просить чтобы я реализовал все методы этого интфейса который из документации, вот почему я не могу его наследовать

Comment: Так вам не нужно его реализовывать. Вы можете его получить из метода. В доке написано, где его можно получить.

Comment: @return cкиньте пожалуйста

Comment: В своём комментарии я имел в виду реализацию. Да. Выразился неточно, потому что реализация интерфейса осуществляется по сути через механизм наследования.

Comment: @V-Mor не через механизм, а через синтаксис наследования. В типе `Type` есть св-во `BaseType` (1) и `GetInterfaces` (много). Так что это разные механизмы.

Comment: Зависит от ваших нужд. Можете использовать [SocketGuild](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.WebSocket.SocketGuild.html)

Comment: @return спасибо за интересное объяснение :) не углублялся в эту тему, теперь буду знать больше

Comment: Всё я всё сделал, я крч сделал по другому не через интерфейс IGuild мне помог @return

Comment: При желании, вы можете написать в ответе ваше решение (хотя бы нормализованный (Shift+Tab) код).